# cv has no member CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to run a bit of code to add trackbars onto some video, it's from the Learning OpenCV Second Edition book, but I can't compile my code and gives the error "namespace cv has no member CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES"

Here's the first bit of the code

```css
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int g_slider_position = 0;
int g_run = 1, g_dontset = 0; //start out in a single step mode
cv::VideoCapture g_cap;

void onTrackbarSlide(int pos, void *) {
    g_cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
    if(!g_dontset)
        g_run = 1;
    g_dontset = 0;
}
```

Comment: cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES is only valid for latest opencv versions. what exactly are you using? (you might need to fall back to CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAME with older versions).

Comment: I'm using cv 2.4.9 with visual studio 2010, and I tried CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAME but had the same result

Comment: sorry , typo, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAME**S** (note the S) and it should be brought in by highgui.hpp.  It's an unnamed enum in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer chappjc, adding the S to the end and taking out the cv:: at the start seems to have fixed my problem